# App Crash On 6.x (Device + Emulator)

Tags: xamarin.ios

got a app that work fine in 5.x but crash on 6.x - tried everything but no proper error logs etc

When the application crash on the device it cause the device to show the Apple logo and I have to do a restore to fix the device. At this same time it also cause the Emulator to crash.

Comment: no logs at all ? not even on the device (through XCode organiser) ?

Comment: The watchdog should not kill your application on the iOS simulator (if it takes more than the *approximatively* 20 seconds allowed). The crash reports would tell more (they are also available, but generally less useful, for the simulator if you look in Console.app).

Comment: No logs not even on device

Comment: It sounds like your app is using so much memory that the OS is crashing. Can you reproduce the issue in a simple test project?

Comment: I don't think its the app itself since after the app crashed the device i can't deploy a simple "Hello World" app since that also cause a crash, I think there is something wrong with the compiler/toolset in the way the deployment is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to bug:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11126

This is a issue in the Xamarin Studio IDE.